# Can not import the app from my project

Tags: django

Why my `app01`  unresolved?

[image]

In my settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app01',
]

...
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],

...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

---

**EDIT**

it runs in PyCharm Terminal.  I use PyCharm CE.

Comment: Does it actually run without errors? is it just PyCharm?

Comment: @Sayse Yes, it runs in PyCharm Terminal.  I use PyCharm CE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyCharm CE does not have Django support last time I checked. Which means your project root isn't added to python path automatically.

Mark the toplevel `testMulToM` as source root (right-click on the path in the tree and choose "Mark directory as"). This will add it to `sys.path` and teach PyCharm to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

you should open `xxx/path/testMulToM/testMulToM` with pycharm not `xxx/path/testMulToM`